# Why does background-size: cover; slow down my jquery animation?

Tags: jquery, firefox, css

I've been struggling to understand why the jQuery animation on a site I've just started building was running so sluggish..  Turns out it is something to do with background-size:cover that I have applied to a large background image on the body tag.

The sluggish performance is only happening to me in Firefox, its fine in safari and chrome and I tried disabling all add-ons so dont think its anything like that affecting things.

When I switch off background-size in firebug my jQuery slideDown effects run smoothly. Put it back on and they run much more jerky.  Same thing happens when I animate using CSS3 transitions instead.

Any ideas why the background-size property is affecting the animations?

The page in question is: http://flc.timidmedia.co.uk/    If you hover any of the boxes on the right hand column you should see then animation.

Comment: Not really an answer but: can't you just make the background the right size? Making a small bg bigger will make it ugly and making a large bg smaller makes it unnecessary big. Another thing I found on your website: If you mouseover / mouseout over the expanding subtext multiple times it keeps folding/collapsing multiple times

Comment: Mmm, but what is the right size?  I've gone with making the image 2560x1440 as thats pretty much the largest resolution commonly available..  sure its a reasonably big file size too...    the whole reason I went with background-size:cover was to make the image 'the right size' for most screen resolutions..   ..I know I have an issue with the animations chaining, but I got sidetracked by this 'issue'.  Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Probably happens because `background-size:cover` has to make additional calculations to render properly.

See this explanation of what needs to happen to make it work.

> **cover**
>
> Specifies that the background image should be scaled to be
> as small as possible,  while ensuring both its dimensions are greater
> than or equal  to the corresponding dimensions of the background
> positioning area.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size

Just guessing, but maybe FF's engine is slow on this one?

Comment: Yeah I figured that it would be a bit more intensive on the browser.. but surely when the browser window isnt being resized you wouldnt have thought it would put that much strain on the browser?

Comment: I know this is an old post but just stumbled across this today and wanted to respond to Tim's comment - Even though the browser isn't resizing it is still moving around DOM elements which requires the browser to redraw and therefore recalculate the background-size.